# Нужно ли название иконы брать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Икона Всех Скорбящих Радости — нужно название иконы брать в кавычки или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Название иконы брать в кавычки не нужно, но слово икона, если только это не начало предложения, пишется со строчной буквы, тогда как все остальные слова в названии - с прописной: *икона Всех Скорбящих Радости*.